# grid-template-areas doesn't work with ReactJS function components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

NOTE: You can view and edit the code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-johnson-honn1y?file=/src/App.js).

I have the following parent component which contains 5 children, 3 of them are React components, while the remaining 2 are regular HTML buttons:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import FormField from "./FormField";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <form className="Form">
      <FormField className="name" title="Name" type="text" isRequired={true} />
      <FormField className="salary" title="Salary" isRequired={true} />
      <FormField className="age" title="Age" type="text" isRequired={true} />
      <button className="submit">Submit</button>
      <button className="update">Update</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The CSS styling for the parent (App.css) is shown below (notice the grid-template-area property):

```
.Form {
  display: grid;    
  grid-template-areas:
    "name name"
    "salary salary"
    "age age"
    "submit update";
  gap: 20px;
}
.name {
  grid-area: name;
}
.salary {
  grid-area: salary;
}
.age {
  grid-area: age;
}
.submit {
  grid-area: submit;
}

.update {
  grid-area: update;
}
```

I expect to see the following based on my grid areas:

[image]

But the actual result is:

[image]

**Where is the problem that prevents my grid from matching the specified areas?**

Comment: I have modified the codesandbox. You can take a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-sanderson-6qenhl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `FormField`s in a div with the grid area class on them.
the FormField adds the class on the input, not itself.

```
<form className="Form">
  <div className="name"><FormField title="Name" type="text" isRequired={true} /></div>
  <div className="salary"><FormField title="Salary" isRequired={true} /></div>
  <div className="age"><FormField title="Age" type="text" isRequired={true} /></div>
  <button className="submit">Submit</button>
  <button className="update">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be possible without extra divs.